# Globally customizing the style of figure captions

Tags: formatting, captions

Is it possible to globally alter the way figure captions are rendered? For example, I might want to wrap all captions in `\textit` to better distinguish captions from regular text.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, please use the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/) package. For instance, to italicize the Figure/Table identifier, use the following line:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=it]{caption}
```

To italicize the entire caption, use the following line:

```
\usepackage[font=it]{caption}
```

To use bold font rather than italics, use `bf`. To use bold and italics simultaneously, use `{bf,it}` or `{it,bf}`. You can monospace with `tt`, remove serifs with `sf`, or ensure serifs with `rm`. See [this page](http://www.forkosh.com/pstex/latexcommands.htm) for further font attributes that you might wish to set. Please consult Chapter 2 of the [`caption` package documentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDcQFjAC&url=ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf&ei=tts8T9LIIsvViAL_sPXDAQ&usg=AFQjCNER2wBm_j0vjo-DICbr2ruq5LD0vQ) for further options that can be set to effect caption customization.